# Website Version but Mobile Sized Screen in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I cannot find a tutorial to make flutter is remain to its size no matter it's in mobile or website version. Has everyone ever tried to do like that? What setting should I add to my code? I want my mobile sized version is in the website version too. Hope y'all get what I mean. Thanks in advance.

Here is the illustration https://pasteboard.co/JtTOEJ8.png

Comment: put it into some div, set it's width to desired, height: 100vh, display:block, margin-left and margin-right to auto? https://jsfiddle.net/dfum8keL/

Comment: how about with Flutter? @FlashThunder

Comment: oh sorry, didn't notice the tag